# Is there any way to download excel file in R studio

Tags: r, json, excel, api

I make an API connection and is reading data directly through it, It's in JSON format, I stored that JSON in an excel file and is planning to download it from R studio, to a particular location in my computer. Is there any way to download an Excel file in R studio. I am really new to R studio not sure if there is any way available or not. This is the code that I have done so far.

```
write.xlsx2(res, file='JSONData.xlsx')

read.xlsx2("JSONData.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are lots of people here who are eager to help, but to make this work best, it's good to review the forum guidelines about how to ask a good question. It will be hard to help you without more detail about what happens when you run your code, and how the result is different from what you want. If you can, it's best to create a reproducible question so that other people can generate the same kind of issue you're dealing with.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info